# Display a default disabled, selected option as a placeholder in a vue select input

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js

I am attempting to create a form with a select with a bunch of options that are pulled from a database, and also one option that will be a placeholder that will say something like "Choose a title".

The issue I am experiencing is that although the placeholder option is indeed selected and is disabled correctly, it does not display in the actual input list before anyone clicks on it as the selected option.

### **Required behavior:**

Before a user has clicked on the dropdown at all, they should see a dropdown that has the grayed out text of a disabled item that says "Choose a title". When they click on the dropdown, they can then choose from the list of titles that are grabbed from the database.

### **Current incorrect behavior:**

Before a user has clicked on the dropdown at all, they see an empty dropdown menu with nothing written or selected in it. Once they click on the dropdown, it shows that the disabled option is currently selected even though the text doesn't show in the input box (but does in the dropdown), and are able to select one of the non-disabled options that is pulled from the database.

What am I doing wrong here? I've found several things online that tell me to do it the way I have it right now. Here is my code:

```
<label for="TitleSelector">
   What do you want to edit?
</label>
<select name="TitleSelector" id="TitleSelector" v-model="selectedTitle">
   <option value="" disabled selected>Choose A Title</option>
   <option
    v-for="(title, index) in allTitles"
    :value="title"
    :key="index"
   >
     {{ title }}
   </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 6):

I've got it, it works if I v-bind the value of the disabled option like so:

```
<option :value="null" selected disabled>Choose A Title</option>
```

Comment: Nicely done. That saved me. I just copied `v-model="x.y"` from my `<select>` and changed `v-model` to `:value` on the `option[selected][disabled]` (`<option :value="x.y" selected disabled>`).

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation (Especially for Using Objects)

It seems nobody really explains *why* you need to do x or y and they just say "*do `<option value="" selected disabled>`*" with all sorts of variance.

Here's what's going on... In normal HMTL you just need to indicate `selected` & `disabled`. Vue, however, is always going to try to match any `option[value]` with the `select[v-model]` value. So whatever your *default value* is for that model is what needs to be the `option[value]`.

In my case, the `v-model` reflected an entire object and the option was always getting selected at first but then, when any input for the rest of the form changed, it was reselecting the placeholder option (for some reason). This was because I had written it as...

###### My Model

```js
class Campaign {
    ...
    reward = new Reward();
}
```

###### DON'T

```html
<select v-model="data.reward" required>
    <option :value="data.reward" :selected="data.reward.type === 'unset'" disabled>-</option>
    <option :value="reward" v-for="reward of rewards">...</option>
</select>
```

Changing my model to...

```js
class Campaign {
    static reward = new Reward();
    ...
    reward = Campaign.reward;
}
```

... was actually the real trick to get it working. I could then write...

###### DO!

```html
<select v-model="data.reward" required>
    <option :value="Campaign.reward" :selected="data.reward === Campaign.reward" disabled>-</option>
    <option :value="reward" v-for="reward of rewards">...</option>
</select>
```

... or more concisely ...

###### BETTER!

```html
<select v-model="data.reward" required>
    <option :value="Campaign.reward" selected disabled>-</option>
    <option :value="reward" v-for="reward of rewards">...</option>
</select>
```

### In a Nutshell

**The `option[selected][disabled]` *always* needs to be bound to whatever your default value of the model is**.

In other words, in the OP's case, the solution for `option[:value="null"]` *only works because their default value **also** is `null`*. If it is an object then you need to have some way to reference that exact same object (instance), in the machine's memory heap, as the placeholder option's value.